# DynamoDB queries take 2000ms for no obvious reason

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I am using DynamoDB to query some data. At a bottom you can see number of miliseconds for certain percentage of requests.

Most of the time DynamoDB works fine with about 100ms response time. (there are only queries on Primary Key or Indexes). About 0.4% requests take more than 800ms (which is the limit the service need to provide response) even at "calm" times. Its not perfect, but good enough.

However certain load (which is not even big) triggers DynamoDB behaviour that causes about 5% of requests to have 2000ms response times. There are several queries in one request, but if one of these queries take more than 800ms, whole request is terminated by caller.

We are using Node.js and this is how we use the AWS library:

This is how we initiate the library

```
const dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({
    region: config.server.region,
});

/// ...

dynamodb.query(params).promise()
```

Example of query

```
{ 
   "TableName":"prod-UserDeviceTable",
   "KeyConditionExpression":"#userId = :userId",
   "ExpressionAttributeNames":{ 
      "#userId":"userId"
   },
   "ExpressionAttributeValues":{ 
      ":userId":"e3hs8etjse3t13se8h7eh4"
   },
   "ConsistentRead":false
}
```

Few more notes:

- CPU of service is currently autoscaled to be below 10%, higher load or cpu usage does not make the service work worse, we even tried to reach 50% with same response times
- There is no "grow" of response time. Its usually less than 100ms and then out of nowhere its 2000 for 1-5%. As you can see in the graph
- The queries do not use ConsistentRead
- We are using Global Tables in 4 regions. This happens in all regions (the service is deployed independently in all 4 regions as well)
- DynamoDB metrics for tables used do not show any spikes in response times
- Service is deployed in ECS Fargate, but it was deployed before in ECS EC2 with same results
- All tables in all regions are on-demand
- The 2000ms delay happen anywhere in service during request lifetime when querying dynamodb (=happens for different queries, even for different tables)
- When I repeat the same request that took more than 2000ms again, it takes only 100ms or less

[image: graph01]
[image: graph02]

Comment: Can you post the value of dynamoDb read/write capacity set on the dynamoDb table? it seem's that you set it to low for the number of query

Comment: @gccodec - its "on-demand"

Comment: I think that can be an issue caused by the ondemand read/write capacity.
Ondemand set the r/w capacity based on previous traffic history. So if there are a fast increase of the traffic the first call on the db can have some time delay issue.
In this case I suggest to write a ticket on AWS support center.

Comment: @libik Have you figured out the cause of it? We experienced similar issue, but the rate of slow query is much lower. Our queries normally returns in about 10ms, but once it spikes, it can take a few minutes. As you said, DynamoDB metrics doesn't show any spike. So, I guess it could be nodejs library is causing the issue. What if you use 'keepAlive' in the httpOption. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/node-reusing-connections.html